# Last Harka is showing before the first character of the line in Arabic Reshaper on Android

Tags: android, arabic, right-to-left

I am using this [Amazing Arabic Reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper) for my app on `Android`, Every thing works fine, but there is a little problem with it that it always shows last Harka (Harki) before the first character of the line in Android, I have also tried `gravity right` etc

It works fine for Android version greater 2.3.3, as this is a right to left language I dont understand why its not working fine on Android versions less then 2.3.3 you can see the image below for better understanding.[image]

I also tried that I moved the last Harka to the first character of the line, it works fine for first line only BUT on the after that same issue comes. Kindly help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Haraka is a proper Arabic word means Diacritic (e.g. Fatha, Dammah, Kasrah)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the reason of this is [the Bidi rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/); when you mix letters and symbols the last symbol does not follow the sentence direction unless it is between two letters. That's why you are getting it only with the last Haraka.

For Android versions that support bidi natively, you should **not** use the Arabic reshaper library. Only use it for Android versions that does not connect Arabic letters properly. You can add an option in your application where the user decides weather or not Arabic letters are displayed properly.

Alternatively, you can have in your application an exhaustive list of Android version and weather or not it supports Bidi natively, so you automatically decide when to use the Arabic reshaper.